# Sending SMS through GSM modem to mobile phone

Tags: vb.net, sms, gsm, modem

Using VB.NET I need to send a SMS using GSM modem to a mobile phone.

Currently I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If serialport.IsOpen Then
        serialport.Close()
    End If
    Try
        With serialport
            .PortName = ComboBox1.Text
            .BaudRate = 96000
            .Parity = Parity.None
            .DataBits = 8
            .StopBits = StopBits.One
            .Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend
            .DtrEnable = True
            .RtsEnable = True
            .NewLine = vbCrLf
        End With
        serialport.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    serialport.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCr)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    serialport.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & "destination" & Chr(34) & vbCr)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    serialport.WriteLine("test message" & vbCrLf & Chr(26))
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
End Sub
```

The thing is, it seems that this code is not working.

Can you check if this is correct or not. Or just give me some threads which can help me with this.

Comment: Can't tell exactly what is wrong with your code, but the `BaudRate` doesn't seem right: `.BaudRate = 96000`. It should be 9600.

Comment: Hey @dan radu can you give me some example about this ?

Comment: I didn't communicate directly with a GSM Modem, but I used a library which worked well with my `GSM Modem Wavecom Q2303A`. The library is called [`mCoreLib`](http://www.logixmobile.com/products/mcorelib/index.asp) and the trial version adds an ad to every message sent.

Comment: oooh, that library. i thought it's nothing, well, i've got to try that. thank you again.

Comment: Have you tried sending messages with this modem using hyperterminal? Not all GSM Modems support text mode.

Comment: I think that your `"destination"` should probably be the phone number you are wanting to send the message to.  You should also check the return status from the modem instead of just pausing.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me and can send a message to your phone:

```
{
    SerialPort1.WriteLine("AT")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
    SerialPort1.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
    SerialPort1.WriteLine("AT+CSCA=" & Chr(34) & MessageCenter & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
    SerialPort1.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & PhoneNumber & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
    SerialPort1.WriteLine(Message & Chr(26))
    MsgBox("Send")
}
```

> Note; this code I tried and received message from my phone like this; "?????#$??#????".